# Changing interactive report column order in Oracle APEX 5.1

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am creating an interactive report in APEX 5.1 and I modified the underlying query, adding a field. I assigned to the new field sequence `2` so that it is displayed second on the report but it displays last. How can I change its order in the report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- While logged into the APEX Builder, run the page.
- Click on the Interactive Report's `Actions` button and select `Columns`.
- Select the column and use the arrows to move it up or down, then press `Apply`.
- Click on the Interactive Report's `Actions` button and select `Report` > `Save Report`.
- Select `Primary` and press `Apply`.  (Note the text "The current report settings will be used as the default for all users." that appears in this dialog.)